# Android: smooth animation with thread and invalidate()

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

I am currently trying to animate a bar chart with bars moving up and down depending on value changes.

I use a separate thread to handle the drawing with a refresh rate of 20ms and use postInvalidate() to redraw my view.

The problem I am running into is that after a postInvalidate the onDraw doesn't always get called immediately, therefore the animation isn't very smooth.

I have tried using a fixed increase in barsize in each onDraw() and also dynamic one, neither of those methods produces a really smooth animation and results in "lags" if it takes too long to call onDraw().

Additionally I also tried using a SurfaceView instead of a View also without much success.

Is there anyway to create a smooth animation this method? Or should I resort to something different?

Answer (score 0):

Normally we don't use additional thread to handle animation steps. Just stick to the existing facilities providing by the animation framework.

Here is an example of smooth zoom animation:

```
    private static  class ZoomAnimation extends Animation {
        private float mFrom;
        private float mTo;
        private MyView mMyView;

        public ZoomAnimation(MyView v, float from, float to) {
            mFrom = from;
            mTo = to;
            mMyView = v;
            setDuration(160);
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            float f = mFrom + ((mTo - mFrom) * interpolatedTime);
            mMyView.setPerformZoom(f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately that won't work me as I am drawing the bars on canvas with drawRect()

Comment: For this case you just maintain the status/progress in your customized control widget and perform drawing / post invalidate() in the onDraw() method.

Comment: the problem I am facing is that i can't control the time between my postInvalidate() call and the actual call of onDraw(), because it is up to the OS, eg: I call every postInvalidate() every 20ms in my thread, sometimes the OS calls the onDraw in 30ms sometimes in 150ms which results in slowdowns with a fixed bar height increase or "lags" with dynamic bar height increase (depending on time between onDraws())

Comment: Sure you cannot control the drawing time, so this should be done in a "best effort" manner. You always post invalidate and in each calling to "onDraw()" method, you check it time stamp to decide whether you need to draw something new.

Comment: best effort drawing doesn't really work, because it always results in lags or slowdowns, so I guess I have to think of a different implementation to get a smooth animation for my bar chart, thanks for your efforts though

Comment: So this situation indicates that your implementation is of low efficiency. Check your drawing code and optimize the algorithm.